# How to find if JPanel has null components?

Tags: java, swing

```
if (cardPanel.getComponent(0) != null) cardPanel.remove(0);
```

I need to remove anything potentially on the cardPanel which is a JPanel...
if there is nothing then it should not attempt to remove.

Comment: A Container can't have null components

Comment: This smells of being a possible XY Problem, in that the best solution to the overall problem might be another approach entirely, such as using a CardLayout to swap views, or to have better ways to get references to objects that you want to manipulate state or behavior. You might do well to describe your overall problem in greater detail and to focus less on your current solution attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
cardPanel.removeAll();
```

There is no need to check if there are any components on the panel.

Answer (score 2):

Only remove JPanel? You can try this:

```
Component[] components = cardPanel.getComponents();    
for(Component c : components)
    if(c instanceof JPanel)
        cardPanel.remove(c);
```

Comment: (1-) Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @camickr With your solution of cardPanel.removeAll(), how sure are you that all existing components are JPanels?

Comment: We placed different emphasis on the words "which is a panel". You seem to think it means lets remove the JPanels but keep the JTextFields, JButtons etc. Trying to understand the context of the entire question, not just 3 words I tend to think it means the variable "cardPanel, is a JPanel" and therefore the OP is trying to remove anything on the cardPanel. Must admit I missed your check to see if the component was a JPanel before removing it. I can't remove the down vote unless the answer is modified.

Comment: Down vote undone but do you really think this answers the question? Do you really think the OP wants to remove only JPanels and leave all other Swing components on the cardPanel? I guess only time will tell, if the OP ever bothers to reply :)

Answer (score 0):

One potential way would be to use the following code to first check if there is anything there, before the potentially erroneous situation where a component is removed from and empty JPanel:

boolean isComponentInPanel(Component component) {
    return
        java.util.Arrays.asList(panel.getComponents())
            .contains(component);
}

Comment: `where a component is removed from and empty JPanel` - that statement makes no sense. If the panel is empty there is no component to remove, so nothing will happen.. There is no need for the check. And if you did do a check you just use the getComponentCount() method, this is what the removeAll() method does.

Comment: i got errors when it was empty... so something did happen.

Comment: Your code is wrong. If you just use the removeAll() method you will not get errors. Read the comment about the XY problem. You are doing something strange in your program and then doing something strange to try and fix the problem. When you have a problem post the code that demonstrates the problem. Minimal code that demonstrates a problem is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Post a `SSCCE` with every question so we can see what your are doing and so we don't have to guess the context of your question.